# Mysql : is it possible to select those values

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have a table has some info like this

```
id   | message
1    | x:something 
2    | y:something else
3    | z:something else too
4    | x:something else too
5    | y:something else too
6    | z:something else too
```

Is it possible to select (x,y,z) with no duplicate, but the length of x,y,z is n't always the same, but there will always be a (:) at the end of that string.

Is that possible in mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ':', 1) AS strippedField
FROM tableX
```

Answer (score 2):

yes - you can select where the `SUBSTR` is what you want to match on.

or possibly use `REGEX` to match the patterns...

Comment: ... and fulfill the "with no duplicates" condition by eg. a `GROUP BY`

Comment: or `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index